# condition in .xinitrc not satisfied, don't know why

Tags: x11, xinit, xrdb

I have a condition in `.xinitrc` that is not met, and I don't understand why:

I have the `.Xresources` file in my `~` (with read permissions), and my `~/.xinitrc` contains a line with

```
[[ -f ~/.Xresources ]] && xrdb -load ~/.Xresources &
```

However the condition between double brackets is not met. Why is that? The file exists and is located in my home!
If I change the line to this,

```
xrdb -load ~/.Xresources &
```

Then it works, and also works if I run `[[ -f ~/.Xresources ]] && xrdb -load ~/.Xresources` from bash.

Why is not working in `.xinitrc`?

My solution for the moment was to put directly the second line, however I don't understand why the condition is not met.

Comment: Is your `.xinitrc` a bash script, or a sh script? the `[[ ... ]]` extended test syntax may not be supported in the latter

Comment: That was it!! In fact my .xinitr runs as a shell script, many thanks!!

Comment: No need to put the `xrdb` command in the background, that one does not block -- and you want the resources to be loaded before the window manager starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is in the comment from @steeldriver:

> Is your .xinitrc a bash script, or a sh script? the [[ ... ]] extended
> test syntax may not be supported in the latter